# Vector and Arraylist

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

Since they are both classes of the Collection Interface class, can I declare a vector and display it as an arrayList? My professor says I can but I really don't see how that would work. Is she wrong or is there really a way to display a vector as an arrayList? This is just me being curious.

Comment: What do you mean by "display a vector as an arraylist"?

Comment: I don't know, my professor just said we can do that without saying anything else. I guess she means we can use those 2 interchangeably? Like we can use a vector as an arraylist and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, both implement the `List` interface. So if you're programming to an interface, you could change the underlying implementation without any errors in your code (but may some performances changes).

Comment: As others have mentioned, they are interchangeable to some extent because they are both implementations of List. But, whilst they're theoretically interchangeable in this way, Vector is essentially an obsolete class nowadays. Its raison d'être was originally to provide a synchronised list implementation, but nowadays you would generally achieve this via Collections.synchronizedList(), or indeed via one of the newer concurrent collections depending on your requirements.

Comment: I agree with previous comments.  I think that you probably misheard what your professor said ... or she misspoke.

Comment: I see. I'll ask my professor again if I have a chance. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the two:

```
public class Vector<E>
extends AbstractList<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable

public class ArrayList<E>
extends AbstractList<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable
```

These are two seperate classes and cannot be interchanged. You can do the following:

```
AbstractList<String> = new ArrayList<String>();
AbstractList<String> = new Vector<String>();

List<String> = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> = new Vector<String>();
```

If you want to form an ArrayList from a vector or vice-versa, you can do the following:

```
Vector<String> newVector = new Vector<String>(oldArrayList);
ArrayList<String> newArrayList= new ArrayList<String>(oldVector);
```

Comment: The `addAll()` method and copy-constructors could be mentioned in the answer, too.